# Use variable to replace all occurrences of specific string

Tags: javascript

How do I use a dynamic variable as first argument in `replace` function?

I have this code that searches a user specified string:

```
 var query = jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val()).toLowerCase();
 console.log(query + ' was searched')
 jQuery('.one-reference').each(function () {
    var jQuerythis = jQuery(this);
    if (jQuerythis.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query) === -1) {
       jQuerythis.fadeOut();
    }
    else {
       jQuerythis.html(jQuerythis.html().replace(/&/g, '<strong>$&</strong>'));
       jQuerythis.fadeIn();
    }
 });
```

This `replace(/&/g, '<strong>$&</strong>'))` is not working.

I want to wrap all occurrences of `query` with `<strong>` tags.

Comment: can you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Shouldn't you then search for `query` instead of `&`?

Comment: @Stefan it will search for the sting `query` then ... not the string inside variable `it will search for `

Comment: FYI: your problem is unrelated to jQuery. [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is a standard JavaScript function.

Answer (score 3):

As you're searching for an arbitrary value within the html you will need to create a `RegExp` object and use that in your `replace`.

```
if (jQuerythis.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query) === -1) {

  jQuerythis.fadeOut();
} else {
  var queryReg = new RegExp(query, 'g');
  jQuerythis.html(jQuerythis.html().replace(queryReg, '<strong>$&</strong>'));
  jQuerythis.fadeIn();
}
```

Also you will first need to escape (`\`) any characters in your query variable that have a special meaning in regular expressions (`^$[]+()\/-` for example) -

```
query = query.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
```

(from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions))

See [Regular Expressions at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for a more in depth discussion on regular expressions.

Comment: Be sure to mention that inputting `+` or `[]` as parts of the `query` will mess around with the regex if they're not properly escaped.

Comment: He could also use a function to clean the string `query` like:
`function replaceScapeChar(value) {
return value.replace(/([\[|\]|\||\(|\)|\.|\*|\+|\{|\}|\$])/g, "\\$1")
}` (Maybe I didn't write ALL the scape characters. Add what I forgot :P)